# JavaScript how to cancel downloading images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I give example with google maps, than we zooming in google maps sending new pictures of maps, but problem in my project is than i use zoom one time it's good because load new images, but than i use two or more zooms, example if i zoom three times very fast: me browser making queue first download first zoom images, second download second zoom images, and third download third zoom images, but i need just download only third zoom images.

Maybe somebody can advise to try something

load images script example:

```
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push('https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images/calendar.png');
imageURLs.push('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif');
imageURLs.push('http://www.linosartele.lt/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/images-9.jpg');

var imgs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    bgCtx.drawImage(imgs[0], 000,0, 100, 100);
    bgCtx.drawImage(imgs[1], 100,0, 100, 100);
    bgCtx.drawImage(imgs[2], 200,0, 100, 100);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a delay before loading the images on zoom so that you don't download every single time a zoom command is fired. I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API so please change the event handler code to match the API.  So something like this:

```
var interval = 500;
var timeOut;
map.zoom(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(loadAllImages(callback), interval);
}
```

Experiment with the interval to see what delay suits you best. The lower it is the more often it will get fired because the more likely it is that someone wouldn't have zoomed multiple times within that time frame. It may end up being a really small number possibly single digit depending on how fast they zoom and how fast the browser registers the zoom event.

Comment: bad idea, here stop's only for very fast zoom's but if i one time zooming and waiting, browser start downloading images, and if i go second zoom again we got queue..

Comment: You could increase the interval to 1 second that way if they zoom multiple times within a second it only downloads images once. Or make it two seconds if you feel that's what your users will be doing. I don't really see any other way other than implementing some sort of delay on the event callback.